# Problem with position in css

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Well i am developing a site and having trouble in CSS please help me to get rid of this issue.

You can see the following image for final results.

http://i51.tinypic.com/5bwpee.jpg

[image: final result should appear after HTML AND CSS]

so i code like that

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="pattern"></div>  <!-- .pattern -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topHeader">

        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- #header -->
```

and CSS is .. actually in the following codes i use gradient image of and use pattern image to overflow the background.

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(images/header_gradient.png) repeat-x;
}

.pattern {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(images/header_transparent.png) repeat;
}

#wrapper {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#F00;
    height:100px;
}
```

so please kindly help me to solve this problem that how i set logo and author details in center of header..

i tried position but maybe it goes wrong.

---

Now i edited my code the results below, but still having problem

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="pattern"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/16i6z9d.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(http://i55.tinypic.com/1zpgny8.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#pattern {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(http://i51.tinypic.com/ao75eg.jpg) repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}

#main {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-103px;
}

#main img {
    z-index:5px;
}
```

after doing all this still having problem that the #pattern over all the layers. so please kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thank you all.

Comment: Which div are the logo and author details in? Or have you not put them in yet?

Comment: Where’s your HTML for the logo and author details?

Comment: Your update seems like a totally different issue. Did your first question get answered?   [I don't see the repeating pattern problem you are talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/calebirie/tKXPA/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a div for your logo and sitename content.
Move the div towards the right with `position:relative; left: 400px` or whatever distance you need.
Float the logo and sitename to have them line up side by side.
Set the container div (`#logoandsitename`) to `overflow:auto;` to contain the floats.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="pattern"></div>  <!-- .pattern -->
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topHeader">
            <div id="logoandsitename">
                <img src="img.source" />
                <span id="sitename">Your Site Name</span>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div> <!-- #header -->
```

**CSS**

```
#logoandsitename {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}

#logoandsitename img {
    float:left;
}

#sitename {
    float:left;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

That pretty much what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need "width:1200px;" in #wrapper?

Why not you try this html?

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topHeader">
            <div id="logo">Logo</div>
            <div id="author">Author Details</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pattern"></div>  <!-- .pattern -->
</div> <!-- #header -->
```

and this css:

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(images/header_gradient.png) repeat-x;
}

.pattern {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:url(images/header_transparent.png) repeat;
}

#wrapper {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#F00;
    height:100px;
}
#logo, #author{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
#author{
margin-left:20px;
}
.topHeader{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```